# If a matrix is invertible, is its multiplication commutative?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is prompted by change of basis problems -- the book keeps multiplying the bases by matrix $S$ from the left in order to keep subscripts nice and obviously matching, but in examples bases are multiplied by $S$ (the change of basis matrix) from whatever side. So is matrix multiplication commutative if at least one matrix is invertible?

Comment: Though I guess $S$ has to be invertible in this case too, since it is changing a set of independent vectors to another set of independent vectors... But the question still persists (not just with respect to change of basis matrices I guess).

Comment: Only diagonal matrix commute with other matrix.

Comment: @Yuan: That's not true. Only multiples of the identity commute with all matrices. Diagonal matrices only commute among each other. In more fancy language: the centre of the matrix algebra is trivial, but the diagonal matrices form a commutative subring.

Comment: @Rasmus: Yuan said "only", so I would say that it is true.  Rephrased: "If a matrix commutes with every invertible matrix, it is diagonal."  Of course, it is better to replace "diagonal" by "scalar" since then the other implication also holds...

Comment: Note to the OP: your question is a perfectly fine one, but it's also a question you could probably have answered for yourself if you tried a few examples (in a sense I will not try to make precise here, "most" pairs of invertible matrices do not commute).  The practice of testing one's questions out with actual examples is both useful and enjoyable -- in sister disciplines, it is called the "scientific method".  I recommend it to you most highly.

Comment: @Pete:If the comment was meant this way, I think that it is formulated in a misleading way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Definitely not.  Yuan's comment is also not correct, diagonal matrices do not necessarily commute with non-diagonal matrices.  Consider $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & b\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
0 & b\end{array}\right]
$$

Changing the order I get 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & b\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & a\\
0 & b\end{array}\right]
$$
Which is different for $a\neq b$.

Hope that helps.  (Sometimes change of basis matrices can go on different sides for different reasons, but without seeing the exact text you are talking about I can't comment)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I make a mistake. The multiplication of a scalar and the identity matrix commute with others. But I forgot the proof.

Comment: That is of course true since constants commute, and the identity can be put wherever we want. But a diagonal matrix and a constant multiple of the identity are very different.  (I have definitely made that commuting mistake before too, it seems quite reasonable actually...)

Comment: Diagonal matrices are very good examples.  A diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries commutes *only* with other diagonal matrices.

Comment: If the field is $\mathbb Z2$ , does the set of nonzero determinant  2 by 2 matrices commute?

Answer (score 9):

In general, two matrices (invertible or not) do not commute. For example
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1\end{array}\right)  =  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1\\
1 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right)  =  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 2\end{array}\right)$$

Also, to change a basis you usually need to conjugate and not just multiply from the left (or just right).

What you do know is that a matrix A commutes with $A^n$ for all $n$ (negative too if it is invertible, and $A^0 = I$), so for every polynomial P (or Laurent polynomial if A is invertible) you have that A commutes with $P(A)$.

Comment: This is a good answer, +1.  Not that it is much different than mine, but I don't know why some answers are never voted.